# How to structure SQL Query to allow for NULLs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using `ANSI_NULLS` set to `ON`. I need to update my query to allow for a parameter to pass in a null value. The query I have below has a `CASE` statement in the `JOIN`. SQL Server does not like the syntax.

I need to have the `JOIN` look for NULLs if the `@MyColumn` parameter is `NULL` or look for the value that was passed in. With `ANSI_NULLS` set to `ON`, I can't just simply set `MyColumn = @MyColumn` since `NULL` equates to NOTHING.  I know I need to use `IS NULL` syntax.

How do I correctly format this query to get the expected results?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE MySampleProc
    @MyColumn INT
AS
    SELECT  
        t2.MyColumn     
    FROM 
        Table1 t1
    JOIN 
        Table2 t2 ON t2.Table2PK = t1.Table2FK 
                  AND CASE 
                          WHEN @MyColumn IS NULL THEN MyColumn IS NULL 
                          ELSE MyColumn = @MyColumn 
                      END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this...

```
SELECT  
    t2.MyColumn     
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Table2PK = t1.Table2FK AND 
    ((@MyColumn IS NULL AND MyColumn IS NULL) OR MyColumn = @MyColumn)
```